# How to call flash on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, connect-flash

**CODE:**

login.ejs

```
<script>
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You have logged in');
</script>
```

header.ejs

```
<div class = "alertMessage">

    <% if (success_msg != false){ %>
        <span class="alert alert-success containerMargins">
            <%= success_msg %>
        </span>
    <% } %>
    <% if (error_msg != false){ %>
        <span class="alert alert-danger containerMargins">
            <%= error_msg %>
         </span>
    <% } %>

    </div>
```

---

**SITUATION:**

This has nothing to do with using flash on the server-side and displaying the message on the client-side: it already works perfectly for me.

This has to do with calling flash from the client or replicating the same behaviour from the client with some other library.

---

**QUESTION:**

The code I showed of course does not work on the client-side, what can I do to replicate that behaviour on the client-side ?

Comment: What is 'flash'? What library are you using exactly?

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? (I have a vague idea, but some of the specifics can vary).

Comment: @str It was connect-flash. It's an npm module.

Comment: connect-flash has not been updated for almost four years. Are you sure you want to use such an old package?

Comment: @Quentin I edited my question. It displays an error message inside the alertMessage div.

Comment: @str Why wouldn't I ? It works perfectly :)

Comment: @Coder1000 Until it doesn't and there is nobody to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The flash is a special area of the session used for storing messages. Messages are written to the flash and cleared after being displayed to the user. The flash is typically used in combination with redirects, ensuring that the message is available to the next page that is to be rendered.

So you need code which:

1. Stores some data somewhere that the client can access between pages
2. Reads that data
3. Deletes it after being read

Start by picking [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload) for option 1 (such as localStorage, or a cookie). The rest should be trivial - the original module is about [80 lines of code, including about 50% comments](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash/blob/master/lib/flash.js) — to implement (but specific to which choice you make).

Comment: Could you please provide an answer with code pertinent to my current situation ? Thx !

Comment: @Coder1000 — No, as I said in the answer: it is specific to your choice of storage mechanism.

Comment: I updated my answer to show all the code I am using. I could answer my own question with the working code, but that's not the point, is it ?

Comment: @Coder1000 — That's server side code. You haven't picked a client side storage mechanism yet. This answer explains what you need to do, it points you at references to help you with that. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, I'm not going to write you a library.

Comment: localStorage then.

Comment: @Coder1000 — So write a function which stores data in localStorage, and one which reads data from it and then deletes it.

Comment: I know how to do that :) My point is: are you going to add working code that answers my question or am I going to have to answer my own question with that code ? I know how to go forward from here, but in the interest of all SO users, including those that may be neophytes, I would like an answer with code.

Comment: @Coder1000 — Neither. You might like an answer with code, but as I said earlier, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: That's your choice :) I will accept your answer as the official one though but will still add my code underneath ^^

Comment: I always try to put code in my answers or my questions, I feel it helps everyone understand better and faster. But I diverge, we simply have a different understanding of essentially the same thing :) Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I used:

```
<div class = "alertMessage">

    <span class="alert alert-success containerMargins" id="successDiv"></span>

    <span class="alert alert-danger containerMargins" id="errorDiv"></span>

</div> 

<script>

        if (localStorage.getItem("success_msg_local") != null) {
            document.getElementById("successDiv").innerText = localStorage.getItem("success_msg_local");
            document.getElementById("successDiv").style.display = "inline-block";
            window.localStorage.clear();
        }
        else if (localStorage.getItem("error_msg_local") != null) {
            document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerText = localStorage.getItem("error_msg_local");
            document.getElementById("errorDiv").style.display = "inline-block";
            window.localStorage.clear();
        }

</script>
```

and replacing `req.flash('success_msg_local', 'You have logged in')` by:

```
localStorage.setItem('success_msg_local', 'You have logged in');
```